# Observers fire too soon

Tags: ember.js, observers

I have problem with observes. When template is loaded, observers on form fields are fire immediately, before any user action. Thanks for any ideas how to fix it :)

This is my route:

```
App.AccountsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Account.create({});
  }
});
```

This is my controller:

```
App.ExpensesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  ...
  amountValidate: function() {
    console.log("amount changed");
  }.observes("amount"),
  ...
});
```

This is my template:

```
...
<div class="small-10 large-10 columns">
  {{input value=amount type='text'}}
</div>
...
```

Comment: what is the exact problem you have with this behaviour?

Comment: should `App.ExpensesNewController` not be `App.AccountsNewController`?